# UNITY: How to repeat a coroutine in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Ran into a little problem while developing a tool. I'm storing a IEnumerator as a variable, and want to run this coroutine multiple times after each other. I'm currently yield returning the IEnumerator. which isn't working, I've found a messy work around which I don't like. I was wondering if there a good way to reset a IEnumerator or run the same IEnumerator after each other multiple times.

```
public IEnumerator MyCoroutine { get; set; }

private IEnumerator Test()
    {
        Debug.Log("Running");
        yield return MyCoroutine;
        yield return MyCoroutine;
        yield return MyCoroutine;
        yield return MyCoroutine;
        yield return MyCoroutine;
    }
```

The following code will only execute the coroutine once.

I've attempted a little work around but I'm not really happy with the result, any help would be apricated.

Comment: Why not just do a for loop with a while needed around it?

Comment: ye very stupid, not the point of the post tho

Comment: Well. It is because you don't necessarily have to  repeatedly  call it. However if you insist you need to add a callback to tell the main thread its finished and then it can decide if it calls it again. Which is a long winded way of basically adding a while loop on it and setting a bool to say dont do it again

Comment: To add on @BugFinder's statement; You could do an infinite `while`-loop on your coroutine, but if something is preventing you from doing that, it might be better to share that problem instead: Or rather, might be better to provide more context on what you are trying to do which doesn't allow you to put a huge `while` loop in your coroutine.

Comment: Could you show how exactly you use this?

Answer (score 0):

The reason your current approach isn't working as expected is that enumerators are stateful, and once they're executed, their internal state progresses. You can't simply yield the same enumerator multiple times and expect it to restart from the beginning each time.

If you want to reuse the same coroutine instance, you can wrap your IEnumerator in a function that returns a new instance of the IEnumerator each time you want to run it.

```
public IEnumerator MyCoroutine { get; set;}

private IEnumerator Test()
{
    Debug.Log("Running");
    yield return RunMyCoroutine(5);
}

private IEnumerator RunMyCoroutine(int times)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < times; i++)
    {
        IEnumerator currentCoroutine = MyCoroutine;
        // Reset the enumerator by rewinding it
        enumerator.Reset();
        if (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            do
            {
                yield return enumerator.Current;
            } while (enumerator.MoveNext());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This should still have the same underlying issue as before. `IEnumerator currentCoroutine = MyCoroutine;` is still using the same instance of `IEnumerator` every time so after the first run to end `MoveNext` will continue to return `false`

Comment: Try to define MyCoroutine as a function that returns a new IEnumerator instance each time it's called:
private IEnumerator MyCoroutine()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.0f);
}

Comment: I did test and your original solution didn't work for what OP is asking for ;) Of course you can just have the method returning the `IEnuemrator` embedded but that is not OP's use case. OP has a property they want to use without having to know the method beforehand or expose it public if it is coming from another class

Comment: `public IEnumerator MyCoroutine() { get; set;}` is not valid `c#` syntax .. something is either a method or a property, it can't be both

Comment: It's a typo error: `public IEnumerator MyCoroutine { get; set;}`

Comment: Now we are almost back to the first approach but you introduced `enumerator.Reset()` => this is [not supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerator.reset#remarks) for the implicit `IEnumerator` returned from a method with `yield` statements, only if you explicitly implement the interface

Answer (score 0):

Your issue currently is that the property always returns the **same instance of `IEnumerator`** which has already run once to end so [`MoveNext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerator.movenext) which is internally used in

```
yield return MyCoroutine;
```

continues to return `false` which marks the end of the routine. You need to always use a **new instance of `IEnumerator`** returned by the original method call.

You could instead store a

```
public Func<IEnumerator> MyCoroutine { get; set; }
```

which stores the method that **returns** an `IEnumerator` rather than a specific instance and then do

```
private IEnumerator Test()
{
    Debug.Log("Running");
    // this now every time calls the underlying method returning a new IEnumerator 
    yield return MyCoroutine();
    yield return MyCoroutine();
    yield return MyCoroutine();
    yield return MyCoroutine();
    yield return MyCoroutine();
}
```

so assuming you have your example routine like

```
private IEnumerator Example()
{
    yield return new WaitforSeconds(3f);
    Debug.Log("Hello!");
}
```

and so far assigned it via

```
someObject.MyCoroutine = Example();
```

using the above you now instead assign it using

```
someObject.MyCoroutine = Example;
```

Comment: @raynaH The [`Func`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.func-2) can be a different one that takes parameters (e.g. `Func<X,Y,Z,IEnumerator>` would expect a method to have a signature like `IEnumerator SomeName(X x, Y y, Z z)`) ... I think it would help to see your actual setup and use case